# Convert XML-String to an Object

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a class `Order`.

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Order")]
public class Order
{
    [XmlAttribute("Counter")]
    public int Counter { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("Conveyer")]
    public int Conveyer { get; set; }
}
```

Now my XML-String is:

```
"<Order xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Counter>3</Counter>
  <Conveyer>1</Conveyer>
</Order>"
```

I tried to convert this string to an object of the class `Order`.
When I run the code below, I get an object of the type `Order` but all its attributes are 0.
What's my mistake?

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(node.ToString());
XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseClasses.Order));
BaseClasses.Order order = (BaseClasses.Order) sr.Deserialize(reader);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `XmlElementAttribute` instead `XmlAttribute`

```
[XmlElementAttribute("Counter")]
public int Counter { get; set; }
[XmlElementAttribute("Conveyer")]
public int Conveyer { get; set; }
```

That would help in Deserializing correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a task like this in my project. Try like this.

```
[XmlElement(ElementName = "Counter")]
public int Counter { get; set; }
```